# JSP : How to put an image in a list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to put an image in each row of my list in JSP. Now, I take this image from website. I'm doing this too in a display jsp and it's working.

Code :

```
<b><spring:message code="tremmer.picture" var="pictureProvHeader" /></b> 
<display:column title="${pictureProvHeader}">
    <img src =
    <jstl:out value="${tremmer.picture}" />width="100" height="50" > 
</display:column>
```

I have added two photos.

In the first one, it's working and in the second one, it's not working.

Image 1 (Display) :

[image]

Image 2 (List with the problem):

[image]

Image 3 (HTML code) :

[image]

Comment: tremmer.picture is not returning a valid image path.

Comment: Can you provide the resulting html code from your browser for the image tags?

Comment: @NicholasHirras Yeah, i left a new image in the post

Comment: @SudhirOjha And what i should change in my code? I'm using in my DB values like : <property name="picture" value="https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/F1Fanatic02.256.673980.jpg" />

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `<img src="<jstl:out value='${tremmer.picture}' />" width="100" height="50" >` ?

Comment: @Hexronimo Same problem, I don´t know what is happening.

Comment: please provide the code for the controller